# Rails 3.2.1: Calling undefined method in view causes test to hang for 30+ seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, rspec2, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm upgrading my app from 3.0.9 to 3.2.1 (ruby 1.9.3-p0, rvm, bundler) and one thing that I haven't been able to track down yet is this problem. I have a controller spec (in spec/controllers) that renders views for each example. The template that it renders can have any undefined method (like calling "- blahblah" in the haml) and it causes the test to hang for over 30 seconds. Here is the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `blahblahblah' for #<#<Class:0x007fa84f76cc90>:0x007fa849c578c8>
```

I ran the debugger and the hang happened when trying to log the error itself. This happens in `activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb line 22`. So is this Rails' fault, haml's fault, or some other library?

Here is my Gemfile just in case something I am using may be the problem:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
source 'http://gems.github.com'
source 'http://gemcutter.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.1'
gem 'rake', '~> 0.9.2.2'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.11'
gem 'htmldoc'
gem 'haml', '~> 3.1.4'
gem 'sass', '~> 3.1.4'
gem 'hpricot'
gem 'curb'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'liquid', '~> 2.3.0'
gem 'httparty', '~> 0.8.1'
gem 'linkedin', '0.1.7', :require => 'linkedin'
gem 'twitter', '~> 2.0.2', :require => 'twitter'
gem 'mime-types', '>=1.16', :require => 'mime/types'
gem 'oauth'
gem 'roxml'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'sax-machine'
gem 'googlecharts', '1.6.7', :require => 'gchart'
gem 'pdf-reader', '~> 0.9.0'
gem 'paper_trail'
gem 'rubyzip', '0.9.4', :require => 'zip/zip'
gem 'activemerchant', '~> 1.20.2', :require => 'active_merchant'
gem 'compass', '~> 0.11.5'
gem 'compass-rgbapng', '0.1.1', :require => 'rgbapng'
gem 'fancy-buttons', '~> 1.1.1'
gem 'ruby-openid'
gem 'RedCloth', '~> 4.2.9'
gem 'koala', '~> 1.0.0'
gem 'scoped_search', '~> 2.3.6'
gem 'wicked_pdf', '0.7.0'
gem 'devise', '~> 2.0.0'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 2.5.0'
gem 'aws-sdk' # required for paperclip
gem 'whois', '~> 2.0.4'
gem 'validates_timeliness', '~> 3.0.8'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.2'
gem 'hoptoad_notifier', '~> 2.4.11'
gem 'savon', '~> 0.9.2'
gem 'escape_utils'
gem 'ajaxful_rating', '3.0.0.beta3'
gem 'acts_as_list', '~> 0.1.3'
gem 'despamilator', '~> 2.0'
gem 'prawn', '~> 0.12.0', :submodules => true
gem 'net-dns', '~> 0.6.1'
gem 'authlogic', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'myspaceid-sdk', '~> 0.1.11', :require => 'myspace'
gem 'in_place_editing', '~> 1.1.2'
gem 'deadlock_retry', '~> 1.1.2'
gem 'query_trace', '~> 0.1.1'
gem 'aasm', '~> 3.0.2'
gem 'vanity', '~> 1.7.1'
gem 'prototype-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.8.1'
  gem 'rspec'

  # one-liner to install these properly: bash < <(curl -L https://raw.github.com/gist/1333785)
  gem 'linecache19', '0.5.13'
  gem 'ruby-debug-base19', '0.11.26'

  gem 'capistrano'
end

group :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'syntax'
  gem 'timecop', '~> 0.3.5'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '~> 1.2.1'
  gem 'cucumber'
  gem 'launchy'
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Should probably file a bug, I may have noticed something similar with slow to throw an exception.  here is a related issue (wrongly named): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225286/helpers-use-a-lot-of-memory-in-rails-3-2

Comment: @Amala Thanks for the advice. I checked the Rails issue tracker on Github and found other people experiencing [the exact same thing](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1525). One of the commenters included a patch which fixed the problem, which I will put as the answer for this question. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to this in the Rails issue tracker on Github (it's still an open bug as of this time). The problem turned out to be that when an error was raised, an instance of `ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet` was inspected, which apparently caused the object to inspect every item it was holding onto. So, the larger the RouteSet, the longer the `#inspect` took. Here is the fix:

```
module ActionDispatch
  module Routing
    class RouteSet
      alias inspect to_s
    end
  end
end
```

For more info on the bug, [see here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1525).