# Helpers use a lot of memory in rails 3(.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

While migrating a rails 2 app to rails 3 I encountered a huge increase in memory used.
After some research I found out the helpers were the problem. Uncommenting any helpers in the view would speed everything up.

Things I tried to find the real issue:

- include_all_helpers = false
- disable parts of the helper files
- clean up the code by refactoring Model.all usages to some faster code

I got a theory now that some helpers might be renamed or deleted, rails starts to search for them and starts searching models / controllers as rescue.

A page request takes up to 5 seconds and using 2 GB of memory.

Anyone got a clue what causes this issue and how to fix or debug it?

Comment: I found out the huge amount of memory used are due to missing methods / missing variables in helper methods. Instead of error handling it just floods the memory for a while and finally crashes.
Found out by crashing the app and waiting 20 minutes for the server to recover, result FINALLY a stacktrace with some TemplateError handler, corrected the error and the page was smooth again.

Comment: I wouldn't say that this is a general problem with Rails helpers. Without knowing what helpers we are talking about it's hard to say where the problem is. My best guess would be recursion and objects kept in memory because they remain referenced. Also check your gem's helpers.

Comment: Helpers are not searched in controllers or models btw.

Comment: Here is a related issue and it has link to the Rails open bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200713/rails-3-2-1-calling-undefined-method-in-view-causes-test-to-hang-for-30-second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by placing this in config/initializers/anti_freeze_hack.rb :

```
module ActionDispatch
  module Routing
    class RouteSet
      alias inspect to_s
    end
  end
end
```

Credits to [Amala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234125/amala) for linking me the right topic :D